# Firebase role based access fails for new users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've followed Secure data access for user groups on the firebase website:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access

Now my roles are as followed:

```
service cloud.firestore {
// Roles admin = 0, owner = 1, writer = 2, reader = 3
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

        function isSignedIn() {
          return request.auth != null;
      }

      function isAdmin() {
            return isSignedIn() && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == 0
      }

    match /projects/{project} {

        function getRole(rsc) {
          return rsc.data.roles[request.auth.uid];
        }

        function isOneOfRoles(rsc, array) {
          return isSignedIn() && (getRole(rsc) in array);
        }

        function canRead() {
            return isAdmin() || isOneOfRoles(resource, [1, 2, 3])
        }

        function canWrite() {
            return isAdmin() || isOneOfRoles(resource, [1, 2])
        }


      allow read: if canRead();
      allow write: if canWrite();
    }
  }
}
```

Now when a new user is created he isn't an admin and he doesn't have projects. 
So actually he should be able to create a new project and his list of project should be empty.

I'm doing this query to retrieve all the projects:

```
  getAllProjectsForUser(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return from(this.fireStore.collection('projects').snapshotChanges().pipe(map((data => {
      const projects: Project[] = [];
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        projects.push(new Project(doc.payload.doc.id, doc.payload.doc.data()['projectName'], doc.payload.doc.data()['companyName']));
      });
      return projects;
    }))));
  }
```

Now everything works when I'm an admin but it doesn't work for people who don't have any projects and are not admin.

I always get Missing or insufficient permissions.
When I run a query in the rules simulator it gives me:

Error: simulator.rules line [16], column [18]. Null value error. Which is on this line:

```
return rsc.data.roles[request.auth.uid];
```

I have no idea how I can solve this? 
I tried changing the query like this:

```
  getAllProjectsForUser(uuid: string): Observable<Project[]> {
    return from(this.fireStore.collection('projects').ref.where('roles.' + uuid, '<', 4).get()).pipe(map((data => {
      const projects: Project[] = [];
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        projects.push(new Project(doc.id, doc.data()['projectName'], doc.data()['companyName']));
      });
      return projects;
    })));
  }
```

but this ofcourse gives the same problem because there is no project with a roles array.

**EDIT**

I found out that when I test the rules in the firebase simulator that it works.
It's just the query to retrieve all my projects where I'm owner|writer|reader that doesn't

screenshot data:

[image]

Comment: It happen to newly create user or all except admin? Have u assign the role? Did you use Firebase Auth? Can I have a look on your sample data (screenshot of your data from Firebase Console)

Comment: I added a screenshot. It happens for every user that is not an admin. I think because I query all the projects and some projects the roles object is null because it doesn't contain your uuid.

Comment: Yes, because there isn't a define user and their role in the project, so when you perform the query to find the role, it always return the problem you got because, at here: rsc.data.roles[request.auth.uid];, it can't find it. therefore you don't have read permission.

Comment: How can I solve this. Because it seems to me that I can't use an if test in the rules to check if it's null and then return empty array?

Comment: Do you mind elaborate more on default project access? For example, all user can view project X no matter what.  Or, you can explain the user flow from the beginning? Like, I login, I click that, etc.

Comment: The user login and then they see all their own projects or where they are part of. So when the user is not part of a project it should not show up in the list of projects. So the default access is that users are not admins and they don't have any projects because they are new. When they create a project they are automatically owner of that project.

Comment: so, where's the problem kick in, the flow seems okay

Comment: That when a newly created user fetches all project firebase returns missing or insufficient permission. Maybe the roles property on my document is not correct it's of type of Object? Because when I add my userId to every project in the roles object it still gives the same error and that should not be possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179166/discussion-between-angus-tay-and-user1007522).